# Find two numbers that multiply to 20 in O(n) time

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

I'm trying to get two numbers that multiply to 20, in O(n) time. Trying to use a hashmap here.

My test case is 
`int arr[] = {2, 4, 1, 6, 5, 40, -1};`

It's giving me array indices 1 and 5, when it should be 1 and 4.

```
public static int[] multToTwenty(int arr[]) {

    HashMap<Integer, Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        if (hm.containsKey(20 / arr[i])) {
            return new int[]{hm.get(20 / arr[i]), arr[i]};
        }
        hm.put(arr[i], i);
    }
    return new int[]{-1, -1}; // Nothing found
}
```

Comment: `HashMap`s aren't guaranteed to work in O(1)

Comment: Here `return new int[]{hm.get(20 / arr[i]), <<arr[i]>>};` you are returning value in array at position 4 which is 5. Change `arr[i]` to `i` if you want to return indexes. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: `hm.get(20 / arr[i])` returns the index of the number `20 / arr[i]` in the array while `arr[i]` returns the (second) number, so you're basically returning an index and a number instead of returning two indexes or two numbers. Which one of them you want to return?

Comment: The use of a hash map seems like overkill to me. You could just work through the list looking for factors of 20 (1, 2, 4, 5, 10 and 20). Whenever you find one, check to see if the corresponding value (20, 10, 5, 4, 2 or 1) has already been found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`20/i` is an integer division, so `j=20/i` does not mean that `i*j == 20`. You need to add additional check:

```
if (20 % arr[i] == 0 && hm.containsKey(20 / arr[i]))
```

And there is another error in your code: you return an element `a[i]` instead of index `i`. You need to return

```
new int[]{hm.get(20 / arr[i]), i};
```

Comment: True, but I don't think that's why he's getting this particular result.

Comment: Thank you. I'm a little confused about the 20 % arr[i] part. Can you give me just one example where I would get the wrong answer by not including it?

Comment: @user2411290, assume that your `arr` is `{2, 9}`. `20 / 9 == 2`, but `2*9` not equal to `20`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: @user2411290, you are welcome! And do not forget that `HashMap` has `O(1)` put/get/contains complexity in average, not in the worst-case (not very realistic though). Strictly speaking, this algorithm has `O(n)` complexity only in an average case.